# JavaScript writted via Script Editor web part does not recognize page elements

Tags: 2013, javascript

In SharePoint 2013 I added a div on a default.aspx like this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Then I added a Script Editor web part on the page, and added this JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
alert(element);
```

The alert box displays null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Page is published and approved.

View the page source and make sure the element is present.

Try to place the script inside `window.onload` event

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    alert(element);
}
```

Comment: brainwashed by new territory. forgetting the basics.